# Sql UNION same tables with additional origin column

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, union

I have two same tables. Each for each year.

- 15_docs:

  id, name, org, slo, dok
- 16_docs:

  id, name, org, slo, dok

Now I want to create view with UNION of both, but I need to know the rows origin.

Output VIEW:

```
id, name, org, slo, dok, year
```

How can I achieve that?
I am using postgreSQL database.

Comment: Why separate tables for each year? Consider having one common table for all years instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 SELECT id, name, org, slo, dok, 'year 2015' FROM 15_docs
UNION
 SELECT id, name, org, slo, dok, 'year 2016' FROM 16_docs
```

**Edit**

This surely works for MS SQL server, have not test it on postgresql

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. I neded to just add " AS 'year'"

Answer (score 1):

you can use UNION & UNION ALL in this case , both give the same result because UNION clause give distinct rows at the end & UNION ALL clause combine all rows of both query result .But in this case ,this 'year'  must create a uniqueness in each row .
Try this query !

```
 SELECT 
        id,
        name,
        org,
        slo,
        dok,
        'year_15 ' as year
    FROM 
       15_docs

    UNION

    SELECT 
        id,
        name,
        org,
        slo,
        dok,
        'year_16 ' as year
    FROM 
       16_docs
```

or

```
SELECT 
        id,
        name,
        org,
        slo,
        dok,
        'year_15 ' as year
    FROM 
       15_docs

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        id,
        name,
        org,
        slo,
        dok,
        'year_16 ' as year
    FROM 
       16_docs
```